# The new version of LXML (4.9.2) does not work with XPath the way it was

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

when I used Xpath according to the code in the book, I found that xpath method did not exist

```py
from lxml import etree
main_page_text = requests.get(url=main_page_url, headers=headers).text  
etree_obj = etree.parse(main_page_text)  
result = etree_obj.xpath()
```

the code above based on lxml 4.9.2

I tried the method on the Internet, but it still didn't work, I can't use xpath at all,it seemed that a new version of the lxml

```py
from lxml import etree
parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding = 'utf-8')
tree = etree.parse('test.html',parser=parser)
r = tree.xpath('//div/text()')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code!

Comment: sorry……it;s my first time to use stackoverflow and English is not my native language.please excuse my typing error.I will modify my problem next time